# adding a map from google to website

Tags: asp.net, google-maps

i have a textbox that i read a text which represent location, i want to convert this location to map after i click a button.

in google maps there is the option to take the existing map and put it in the web site but i cant find how to regenerate the map from the site.

i also prefer the map to look like like the maps presented when you just enter the address to google and not like the map in google maps.

i cant show you a picture because i dont have reputation for that but try to type in google your address and you will see it (add the word map after that if it wont show you the map, not in google maps just in google.com).

is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at what leaflet.js offers : http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start.html

You can generate maps, place markers on it, and much more. I hope it could interest you.

Comment: thanks for the quick comment, it is realy nice but im building the site for someone and he want it to be from google so i cant use it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not very complicated, the map you see is a [**static map**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/)(a simple image)

Use the parameters of the API, e.g.

- `center`(set it to the value of the input)
- `zoom` (0-21)
- `size`(up to 640x640)

...to  create the map.

You'll find the description of additional parameters(e.g. for the creation of markers) in the documentation.

Simple implementation: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/FgGwB/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/FgGwB/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
<div class="mapWrapper fullwidth"><iframe frameborder="0" height="500" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no"
        src="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=EN&amp;q=time+square&amp;aq=&amp;sll=40.716558,-73.931122&amp;sspn=0.40438,1.056747&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;rq=1&amp;ev=p&amp;split=1&amp;radius=33.22&amp;hq=time+square&amp;hnear=&amp;ll=37.061753,-95.677185&amp;spn=0.438347,0.769043&amp;z=9&amp;output=embed"
        width="100%"></iframe></div>
```

Comment: Please update the answer with some details about what the code is doing.